# Sync SXA Tenant with TDS

Tags: sxa, tds

I am using TDS to Sync SXA Tenant\Site, I followed the below steps:

1- Unified Tenant and Site name with other team members

2- Add changed items in rendering variant node

3- After other team members get latest they got error "Parent Item not found" as the IDs are different.

Also, when I tried to deploy the solution it created a new Tenant.

Is there another steps to get this working correctly?

Comment: This error usually come when not sync in the proper order. From main instance its needs to be re-serialize first then other users needs to serialize.

Comment: As this response is months later, I hope you found a resolution. It sounds like your Tenant folder under Sitecore/Templates/Project might not be in your TDS project.